# Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS file system getting corrupted every 2 days or so

Tags: hardware

I was using Windows 7 on an older laptop. I kept getting bluescreen. It would bluescreen in safe mode and there were no restore points.

I didn't have the disk so I installed Ubuntu 16.0.4.  I am a competent command line user in Linux and I was very pleased actually having a desktop for a change.

Every 2 days or so the

/dev/sda6       312524800 961054719 648529920 309.2G 83 Linux

has an inconsistency and I have to run fsck to fix it.  I can tell when it happens because the file system goes read only.

My question is, is the bluescreen on Windows and the problem I am having on Ubuntu related? Am I looking at a failing hard drive here?

Comment: The very probably is related to hardware issue.  Could you boot with live Ubuntu? Doing so, go to disks utility and verify its health.

Comment: On a guess, I'd say that yes, your hard drive is failing.  For a more conclusive answer you might run [S.M.A.R.T. testing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) on your computer.

Comment: Thanks guys. Not really a hardware guy and ran SMART and  SELF TEST FAILED so I better start shopping around.  I am grateful  for some warning.